# How to skip invalid rows while parsing csv file node js

Tags: node.js, node-csv-parse, fast-csv

I am using node js lib **fast-csv** to parse csv and insert into database. In the csv there are rows which are marked are zeros like below

```
row - 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

How to skip these rows which parsing.Below is the code i am using

```
import { createReadStream } from "fs";
import * as pg from 'pg';
const { Pool } = pg.default;
import { parse } from "fast-csv";

const insertdata = async () => {

    let stream = createReadStream("./testfolder/test.csv");
    let csvData = [];
    let csvStream = parse()
        .on("data", function (data) {
            csvData.push(data)
            // console.log(csvData)
        })
        .on("end", function () {
            // remove the first line: header
            csvData.shift();
        });

    stream.pipe(csvStream);
}

await insertdata();

export { insertdata }
```

Comment: Did you try obvious approaches like changing the `data` handler to `if (!Object.values(data).every(value => value === '0')) csvData.push(data);` ?  Where are stuck?

Comment: I am stuck where i dont want to insert 0 value rows into database. Let me try the if ststement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want rows where all the values are zero, then you want to be thinking of something with the following structure:  *If you don't meet some condition, then don't push the data.*

```js
        .on("data", function (data) {
            if (!isAllZeros) {
                csvData.push(data)
            }
        })
```

And you can replace `isAllZeros` with this expression:

```
Object.values(data).every(value => value === '0')
```

This makes use of `Object.values` to get all the values as an array, and `Array.prorotype.every` to see if they're all zero.

---

So it'll look like this:

```
        .on("data", function (data) {
            if (!Object.values(data).every(value => value === '0')) {
                csvData.push(data)
            }
        })
```